# Why does the keyboard continue to control disabled buttons?

Tags: unity

Having the whole panel with all its children including buttons disabled by simple `gameObject.SetActive(false)` doesn't prevent the buttons from interacting (navigation and clicks) with the keyboard. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried `CanvasGroup.interactable` but it didn't help. Then I looked closely at the UI elements and found a *custom component* on them made by the previous developer - something like a custom `EventSystem`. I have no idea what was the need to write a custom event system, but after deleting it everything works as expected.